# ASP.NET Core Show information after insert Personal ID without changing the view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core project that my user will insert a **first personal ID** that will make my view bring several of information about this person.

But there's a condition where my user maybe needs a second personal ID to be show. If this happen, my user will mark a  field, where he will insert the **Second Personal ID**. After that my view needs to show several information about this person like the first one (is bascicly a copy of all fields that i search for the first personal id)

The question is, how can I achieve this? This view is like a presentation for the user, just recovering all fields that I already have in database and with a field in the final of the page, the user can Edit what is missing, but because that condition for  second a Personal Id need to be inserted, how can i make work? Did I need another instance of my view object (now with the second Personal ID) to get this information, and how will I trigger this when I am already inside the view?

Both IDs exists in the database, so will be a second query

Here is where this condition can be applied, all fields

```
<div class="col-12">
            <div class="col-12">
              <select id="GarantiaSelection">
                <option value="selecione">selecione</option>
                <option value="Sim">Garantia Real</option>
                <option value="Não">Garantia Pessoal</option>
       </select>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Then, if the condition is "Não" the second Personal ID is needed:

```
<div>
    <label>Digite o CPF do Garantidor</label>
    < type="text"> </>
</div>
```

After that, it will show fields about this person, like

```
<div class="col-3">
     <label for="Renda Liquida">Relacionamento</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
     <div class="col-3">
       <label for="Renda Liquida">Atualizaçao Cadastral</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Lucas Barros, your question is not clear, and it is hard to understand. To the Personal ID do you mean it is existed in the database, and now you want to update the current user and want to use a text box (type="text") to display current user's Personal ID? And you will use a `<select>` element to let user select the person, then based on the selected value to get the user and display the personal Id, right? As you said, the above operation can be use JQuery Ajax to achieve it, after calling the back-end method, you can get the data. in the Ajax success function set the value on the page.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it´s no clear, my user will insert one first personal ID. After, maybe he needs another, based on the <select> that i wrote. If he needs is where i need to get a text box field to insert this second personal ID, where i need to search on the database, without changing my view.

Comment: This search needs to get the personal ID for me to return another fields inside the database, but now based on this second id, KEEPING ALL THINGS ABOVE THIS FIELD(just update part of view with second id personal information) thats why i having problems, because how i will get this object and send again to the controler to only update this part of my view

Comment: I Updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: So, the second person's information (personal ID and other property) is not present in the database, and when you choose to insert the second person, it queries the database and gets the information of the first person, then generates a new person ID and other properties of the first person, and populates those values in the page/view, right? If that is the case whether the personal ID is auto generated, or this column is an IDENTITY column?

Comment: The second personal ID exists too, my user will insert to get from the database, it will be a second query, but it needs to show in the same page. This column is a IDENTITY Column.

Comment: Ok, you can use JQuery Ajax to achieve it, after calling the back-end method, you can get the data. in the Ajax success function set the value on the page. Refer to the following links: [Working with AJAX in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax) and [Using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages.aspx).